# Laravel 9 migrate: Object of class App\Enums\CaseSeverity could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel

I have an Enum with string cases:

```
enum CaseStatus : string
{
    case Completed = 'completed';
    case Pending = 'pending';
    case Rejected = 'rejected';

    public function color(): string
    {
        return match($this)
        {
            self::Completed => 'badge-light-success',
            self::Pending => 'badge-light-warning',
            self::Rejected => 'badge-light-danger',
        };
    }
}
```

I am trying to migrate the table that uses this enum and set its default column value to `CaseStatus::Pending`

```
$table->string('status')->default(CaseStatus::Pending)->nullable();
```

When I migrate I get the error:

```
Object of class App\Enums\CaseSeverity could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eloquent model casts don‘t work in migration files because you’re not dealing with Eloquent models.

You need to instead use the underlying *value* of a backed enum in any migration commands:

```php
$table->string('status')->default(CaseStatus::Pending->value)->nullable();
```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php

> Backed Cases have an additional read-only property, `value`, which is the value specified in the definition.
>
> ```php
> <?php
> print Suit::Clubs->value;
> // Prints "C"
> ?>
> ```